# optional WHERE clause searching for different fields based on a parameter in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures

[Table Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1d0b3/1):

```
CREATE TABLE offices
    (`office_id` int,`country` varchar(50),`population` int)
;

INSERT INTO offices
    (`office_id`,`country`,`population`)
VALUES
    (1,'AU',20000),
    (2,'US',1200),
    (3,'UK',150000),
    (4,'NZ',1200)

;
```

I'm using an optional where clause in stored procedures like this:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE GetOfficeByCountry(IN yr_val varchar(50))
 BEGIN
 SELECT * 
 FROM offices
 WHERE yr_val IS NULL OR country RLIKE yr_val
 ASC
 END //
DELIMITER ;
```

I was wondering if there's a way to use `CASE WHEN` for different `Where Clause` based on the parameter `yr_where`. If it's 1, then look for values in country field, if 2, look up in the population field:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE GetOfficeByCountry(IN yr_where tinyint(1),IN yr_val varchar(50))
 BEGIN
 SELECT * 
 FROM offices
 WHERE 1 = 1
 CASE yr_where
        WHEN 1 THEN AND country RLIKE yr_val 
        WHEN 2 THEN AND population > yr_val
        ELSE 1 END  
 ASC
 END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't use `case` in a `where` clause like that. But you can also do this

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE GetOfficeByCountry(IN yr_where tinyint(1),IN yr_val varchar(50))
 BEGIN
   SELECT * 
   FROM offices
   WHERE (yr_where = 1 and country RLIKE yr_val)
   OR    (yr_where = 2 and population > yr_val)
 END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
WHERE 1 = 1
AND CASE yr_where
        WHEN 1 THEN country RLIKE yr_val
        WHEN 2 THEN population > yr_val
        ELSE 1
    END
```

The `CASE` expression must be used where an expression is permitted, which is after the `AND`.